How to Reduce Video Loading Time in React App with Auto-Playing Banner Slider?
I have a React app with a banner slider that plays videos automatically on load. While everything works fine, the loading time of the video is quite slow, affecting the overall performance and user experience.
Setup :

React with functional components
The slider uses a video tag to display and auto-play videos
The videos are inside my public/assets directory

The Problem : When the page loads, the video in the banner slider takes a while to load and play. This delay creates a noticeable lag. I would like to improve the video loading time, but I'm unsure of the best practices to achieve this in React.
What I've Tried:

Preloading the video using the preload="auto" attribute
Compressing the video size
Using React.lazy() for lazy loading (though I'm not sure if this applies well to videos)

Question : What are the best practices to reduce the loading time for auto-playing videos in a React banner slider? Are there any React-specific solutions or optimizations I can apply to ensure smoother playback without compromising the page load performance?

What is the video? Is it e.g. an MP4 file? If so, has it been processed with e.g. ffmpeg's -movflags faststart? What does your browser's network inspector look like when you try to start the video?

@NeelBuhecha Video questions need to include the format used. A testable link is better for assessment about "Optimizations I can apply to ensure smoother playback"... For all we know, this could be a 4K video file loaded into a 500px banner space.
